# Is the whole file uploaded into ram while using `copyFileSync` or `copyFile`(from 'fs/promises')?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am using node and I need to copy a file that may be pretty big.
Is it fine to use `copyFileSync`?

I can't find any source about it describing its implementation. I need to know if it works with streams or just loads everything into memory and writes the file.

Small examples

```
import { copyFileSync } from 'fs';
copyFileSync(srcPath, destPath);

import { copyFile } from 'fs/promises';
await copyFile(srcPath, destPath);
```

Comment: I don't know the exact answer to your question but you could try to find it out with a very big (several GBs) file: watch the server's RAM consumption while copying the file.

Comment: I'm surprised to find that the [API documentation doesn't say](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fscopyfilesyncsrc-dest-mode), but it would be shocking if it did. Looking at the source, it uses [`libuv`](http://docs.libuv.org/)'s `uv_fs_copyfile` under the covers. You could go digging in that to find out, or do something empirical as @trsft suggests, but I give it 99.99999% certainty that no, it doesn't copy the entire file's contents into memory at the same time.